# Change div class depending on page/post Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Is there an easier way to do this in Wordpress?

What i'm trying to do is change a header class depending on what page/post user is on to display a different image..

My code - PHP

```
    <?php

    //Services page

    if ( is_page( 'services' ) ) {

    echo'<header class="main_top services_page">';

     }

    //Portfolio page

    else if ( is_page( 'portfolio' ) ) {

    echo'<header class="main_top portfolio_page">';

    }

    //Digital page

    else if ( is_single( 'digital' ) ) {

    echo'<header class="main_top digital_page">';

    }

    //Social Media page

    else if ( is_single( 'social-media-2' ) ) {

    echo'<header class="main_top media_page">';

    }

    //Print page

    else if ( is_single( 'print' ) ) {

    echo'<header class="main_top print_page">';

    }


    //Home page

     else echo'<header class="main_top">';

    ?>
```

I have added a different CSS class for each header class as below

```
  header.services_page{
    background-image: url(images/contentmarketing1-2000x450.jpg);
  }
  header.portfolio_page{
    background-image: url(images/portfolio-2000x450.jpg);
  }
  header.contact_page{
    background-image: url(images/contact-2000x450.jpg);
  }
  header.digital_page{
    background-image: url(images/digital2-2000x450.jpg);
  }
  header.media_page{
    background-image: url(images/socialmedia-2000x450.jpg);
  }
  header.print_page{
    background-image: url(images/print-2000x450.jpg);
  }
  header.audio_page{
    background-image: url(images/audio-2000x450.jpg);
  }
  header.pr_page{
    background-image: url(images/pr-2000x450.jpg);
  }
  header.cm_page{
    background-image: url(images/contentmarketing2-2000x450.jpg);
  }
```

Thanks! :-)

Comment: Seems like a fine code to me... What isn't working?

Comment: Thanks for your answer - theres nothing wrong it works fine, just thought Worpdress maybe had it's own function to deal with different classes on different pages but I can stick with my PHP :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$page_post_title=get_the_title($page_post_ID);

echo'<header class="main_top $page_post_title">';
```

this will finish in just one line.

try it or you can also modify it.